# How are retries handled in the context of branching PCollections?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Apache Beam runners can perform [fusion](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/glossary/#fusion) to optimize the graph execution. However, in certain cases fusion may result in suboptimal performance.
In Cloud Dataflow, this can be avoided by inserting a `Reshuffle` Transform or `GroupByKey`, which breaks fusion, as per [Deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization) . Otherwise, the fusion of several `PTransforms`
results in a fused `Stage`. Notably, a `Reshuffle` is stated to be deprecated, with the Question: ([Apache Beam/Dataflow ReShuffle deprecated, what to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702671/apache-beam-dataflow-reshuffle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)) noting that Dataflow installs a `ReshuffleOverrideFactory` that essentially reduces the `Reshuffle` Transform to a windowed `GroupByKey` followed by iterable expansion.

In the event of a failure, Cloud Dataflow will retry the failed bundle (infinitely for streaming mode, and up to 4 times for batch mode), as per [Deploying a Pipeline#error-and-exception-handling](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#error-and-exception-handling). The retry will only occur on the failing transform in the Apache Beam model,
unless it is coupled (Coupled Failing)

Based on this understanding, I have executed the following Pipelines(simplified for conciseness):

- Pipeline A: `Read Files >> Parse Files (High Fan-out ParDo transform) >> [Write to BigQuery, Write to Pub/Sub]`
- Pipeline B: `Read Files >> Parse Files (High Fan-out ParDo transform) >> [Reshuffle >> Write to BigQuery, Write to Pub/Sub`]

Both pipelines are writing to a non-existent Pub/Sub topic to replicate an error scenario

For pipeline A, we observed the following:

- our `ParDo` (which is parsing the files) is retrying as since it could not write to Pub/Sub.
- system latency is increasing and there is no output to BigQuery as it internally contains a `Reshuffle`, thus every step prior to the `Reshuffle's groupbykey` operation is being retried as part of the fused stage, as we expected (The bundle has an element with an error).

For pipeline B, we observed the following:

- our `ParDo` does not appear to be retrying
- Interestingly, we are seeing data written to BigQuery, even though there are errors reported in the Dataflow Pub/Sub Metrics(and thus expecting a retry to process the file instead of even writing to BigQuery)

Based on my previous question, I understand only the outputs/side effects of a single successful retry will be observed downstream: [How is exactly-once processing maintained during worker failures or bundle retries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578104/how-is-exactly-once-processing-maintained-during-worker-failures-or-bundle-retries). However, Pipeline A appears to be conforming to this observation, while Pipeline B is not. The only difference between these Pipelines is the addition of the `Reshuffle` PTransform, yet both exhibit different behaviour.

In summary, I guess I have the following question:
How are retries handled in the context of a fused stage; in particular, fused stage with branching outputs? e.g. if there is a bundle retry, does it retry all branches or only the failing branch?

Comment: Based on the [Stack Overflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), are you looking for an answer for which one of your 2 questions?